# Looking for the correct way to lock tables in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a situation where a specific transaction has to update the DB before any other transaction can look at a given table.  Specifically, there is a prizing mechanism whereby there is a limited  number of prizes and I'm concerned that if two requests arrive virtually at the same time the second request might find the prize still available by virtue of the first request having not had the time it needs to mark it as not-available.

I'm looking at the documentation for [lock tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html) and it's not clear to me what's going on, and since it's extremely difficult to test this feature (as it requires two requests arriving at the same time), I was hoping for some advice.

My needs are extremely simple. There is only one table that I need to lock, while all the others can go about their business.

```
**request 1**:
lock prizes;
select from prizes;
mark prize as unavailable;
unlock prizes;

simultaneous **request n**
find the prizes table locked and wait for it to unlock //this is not critical, so long as they can just fail gracefully
select [no prize available]
```

As I said, it's CRITICALLY important that the other tables in this DB are completely unaffected by my lock, I got the sense from the documentation that when I lock one table, selecting another table will produce an error that says "other table isn't locked"... I'm probably not understanding this correctly, as that would seem idiotic, but just need to make sure that locking prizes doesn't affect anything else.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect case for a transaction. Note that your tables need to be InnoDB for this to work.

```
start transaction;
select [your_fields] from [prizes_table] WHERE [your_where] FOR UPDATE;
// if is a valid recipient and prize gets taken:
update prizes set available=0 where id=[used_prize_id];
commit;
```

This should do exactly what you expect.

Comment: awesome! this is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: you should also consider the different transaction isolations available and choose the appropriate one: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html

Answer (score 1):

You should simply `LOCK prizes WRITE` to get the semantics you need. Since locking one or more tables prevents you from accessing any tables you have not locked for the lock's duration, you will also need to lock -- either for reading or for writing -- all other tables that you need to do the "mark prize as unavailable" step, if any.

Be aware that if you intend to access tables using an alias, you also need to supply the same alias in the `LOCK` statement. This topic is covered in the documentation, but I mention it explicitly because it could be overlooked.

Comment: right... the caveat that the entire database winds up being locked for the lock's duration is what makes this whole thing untenable, and makes me think I'm missing something obvious... I don't *want to lock the entire database, and doing so will screw up all sorts of non related processes that have nothing to do with this whole prizing thing. Also, I'm not sure I follow your idea with locking for WRITE since process 2 is, first, going to select from prizes (which it MUST not do, since the select is not going to yet reflect the write that process 1 will be performing a split second later).

Comment: @Dr.Dredel: Why the entire database? Also, it goes without saying that you are going to lock before even selecting.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to lock only the record, you can use the `select ... for update` setting `autocommit=0` and using the transaction.

This way the first request select the record and set the lock, then the second request is blocked until the first request commit (or rollback) the transaction or the wait exceeded the timout

Comment: this looks like the better approach than the lock, can you please elaborate on how to implement a select for update? Also, why would I need to autocommit=0? I'm happy to commit the update immediately... or is the autocommit=0 part the mechanism that places a block on the table?

Comment: This may be a bit too heavy-handed, since autocommit=0 will persist for the rest of the thread's life which likely will have unintended consequences. It's better to explicitly use a transaction, so you don't have to remember to set autocommit=1 again (assuming that was the default setting, of course).

Comment: The implementation is something like: `start transaction; select <record> from prizes where <condition> for update; check if the prize is available; set unavailable; commit (or rollback)`. The `autocommit=0` is needed because if autocommit is enable, the row is non locked (by MySql documentation). It is possible also to use the transaction anyway, without setting `autocommit=0`